# What's going on in this picture (old landscaping equipment)?

Tags: landscaping, equipment

This picture, taken in 1967, seems to show some piece of small equipment doing some kind of landscaping.  Is there perhaps a blade coming out the front of whatever he is sitting on?

[image]

EDIT

Based on the answer received, I found a picture of a [trencher from the 1960s](https://www.vermeer.com/na/about-us/game-changers?hl=en-US):

[image: Vermeer trencher]

EDIT 2:

I emailed Thomas Berry, the Archivist and Editor at the Historical Construction Equipment Association, and he said "From what I can tell the machine is a miniature crawler tractor for work in confined areas. Can’t tell what the attachment is on the end away from the camera, but it’s likely a bulldozer blade or possibly a trencher for digging a narrow trench."

Comment: It is very difficult to tell. Maybe a soil mover, but I think a soil compactor: In front it seems that there is a huge wheel, and not the belts.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a trencher or more likely a cable plow. Cable plows like backhoes/diggers can often be operated normally in either forwards or backwards directions. In this shot the operator is looking backwards so the controls are behind his back. To move to a new location he would turn around and the controls would be in front.

If it was a trencher we would see a lot more soil piled up from where the work is being done. Cable plows disturb a lot less soil, moving a very narrow channel to get the cable in. Note too what looks like guards covering the wheels/tracks which might come in handy if working in a lot of loose soil.

Looks like a crank handle hanging off the front/back/right side plus the long handled spades lying down on the ground. If this was a gardener working the spades would be neatly leaning up somewhere safe and not ready to be tripped over or have handles splintered.

Comment: Also used for sprinkler systems and drain line installation. There are unimaginable miles of buried clay tile field drain lines in farm fields in the US. A headache when laying oil/gas pipelines.